# PHP: Get the keys with the longest string in an associative array

Tags: php

I want to first get the keys with the same values and then keep the keys with the longest string. Here is the code compiled so far:

```
<?php
$data = array('Anna' => 1, 'Ann' => 1, 'Tommy' => 100, 'Tom' => 100);
$total = array_count_values($data);
$filtered = array_filter($data, function ($value) use ($total) {
return $total[$value] > 1;
});

print_r($filtered);
?>
```

The current output:

```
Array ( [Anna] => 1 [Ann] => 1 [Tommy] => 100 [Tom] => 100 )
```

My expected output:

```
Array ( [Anna] => 1 [Tommy] => 100)
```

Many thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not necessarily the most optimized solution, but you could write it up using simple check:

```
$data = array('Anna' => 1, 'Ann' => 1, 'Tommy' => 100, 'Tom' => 100, 'Dan' => 200, 'Danny' => 200);
$total = array_count_values($data);

$filtered = array_filter($data, function ($value) use ($total) {
    return $total[$value] > 1;
});

foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $foundKey = array_search($value,$filtered);
    if($foundKey){
        if(strlen($foundKey) < strlen($key)){
            unset($filtered[$foundKey]);
        } elseif(strlen($foundKey) > strlen($key)) {
            unset($filtered[$key]);
        }
    }
}
print_r($filtered);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to post it after even answer is accepted but I have simple hack for this using `ksort()` and `array_flip()`:

```
$data = array('Anna' => 1, 'Ann' => 1, 'Tommy' => 100, 'Tom' => 100, 'Dan' => 200, 'Danny' => 200);
ksort($data);
$result=array_flip(array_flip($data));
print_r($result);
```

`ksort()`: Sort an array by key

`array_flip()`: Flip all keys with their associated values in an array

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/TPBMX)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much for your help.